# Accessing member array of class using containing class array through pointer - contained array of class object is private

Tags: c++, gnu

I have as a class member an array of that class (`obj`) and I would like to create array of the `Box` class (which is the containing class) and access  `xyz obj[5];` through a `p` pointer object member of that `Box` class.

The `obj` array is **private** but I think I can access it using pointer. Am I correct?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class xyz{
public:
int x;
};
class Box {

   public:
      // Constructor definition
     
      Box ()
      { 
        cout<<"without constructot"<<endl;
      }
      xyz *p=obj;   
      
   private:
    xyz obj[5];
     
};
int main()
{

    Box b[5];;
    Box *p=&b[0];
    (b+2)->(obj)->x=5;
    //cout <<(b+2)->(obj)->x<<endl;     


}
```

exception thrown at `(b+2)->(obj)->x=5;`

this

```
  error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
   28 |  (b+2)->(obj)->x=5;
      |         ^
    main.cpp:28:10: error: ‘obj’ was not declared in this scope      28 |  (b+2)->(obj)->x=5;
      |          ^~~
```

Comment: Depends on what you're asking. You can't access `obj` directly through a pointer to a `Box` (as you see on the error). You can access and manipulate `xyz* p` though, which points to `obj[0]`. `(b+2)->p->x` gives what you want, but why make `obj` private if you're going to expose it nevertheless?

Comment: Since `obj` is a `private` member of `Box`, `(b + 2)->(obj)` will fail (since the member `obj` is inaccessible in `main()`).   However, the member `p` of `Box` is initialised, for each instance of `Box`, to point at the first element of the array `obj`.   So `(b + 2)->p->x` will work.       That said, it is bad practice to have a `public` member of a class (the member `p` of `Box`) that provides unfettered access to a `private` member of the same class (the member `obj`).   The point of making a member `private` is to limit what code can access it.

Comment: @Lala5th Is this correct ( (b + 2)->(p+1) )->x = 5;?

Comment: @Peter Is this correct ( (b + 2)->(p+1) )->x = 5;?

Comment: @user786 `((b + 1)->p + 1)->x = 5` would be the correct way to address this, but you should use something like: `b[1].p[1].x = 5`. It greatly improves readability

Comment: @Lala5th I did this way so I can learn more about pointers because I imagine this is how stl is implemented with lots of use of pointers in iterator and this and that. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: It is true that implementing the C++ standard library (and iterators for standard containers) would require understanding of pointers. I wouldn't bet they would use pointer syntax like you are though - your syntax is, as you are demonstrating, hard to read and also hard for mere mortals to get working right, which isn't a good thing in libraries that lots of people (e.g. customers of compiler vendors) will use and expect will "work out of the box".   Also, BTW, your terminology is way out of date - what was the called STL (over 20 years ago) is now a part of the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues in your code. First, I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish using the parentheses around `obj` but the member access operator (`->`) doesn't work like that – it must be followed *immediately* by the member's name.

Maybe what you want is something like this: `( (b + 2)->obj )->x = 5;` ? However, the outer parentheses are not necessary in such an expression, because `->` has left-to-right associativity (although you can use it for clarity).

However, even with that modification, you are still trying to access a **private** member of the class from outside the definition of that class, and that is not allowed. Generally speaking, if a member is `private`, then you can only access it *from within member functions* (or friend functions) of the class.

As a final observation: I'm not sure why you are using `(b + 2)` when you can just use `b[2]`. Did you mean to use the pointer (`p`) that was assigned the address of `b[0]` in the previous line (as in `(p + 2)->obj->x = 5;`)?

---

As a footnote, I would strongly suggest that you read the following Stack Overflow posts:

1. [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073)
2. [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10871073)

Comment: @user786 No. Your original idea (using `b + 2`) does work, it's just that I don't understand why you're using that, especially as you have declared a pointer (`p`) that holds the address of the array. Anything following the `->` must be **just the name of a member**.

Comment: Is this correct `( (b + 2)->(p+1) )->x = 5;`?

Comment: Can u please tell

Comment: No. Any special punctuation or other character after the `->` will be an error. ***Only the name of a member of the class pointed to is allowed.***

Comment: Then how to access p+1? Which will be obj[1]`

Comment: Assuming all other issues are fixed, then `(b + 2)->p` will point to the `obj[0]` member, so we can increment the result of that *entire expression*: Either `( (b + 2)->p )[1]` or `( (b + 2)->p ) + 1` should do the trick.

Comment: Is the use of pointers is common is real projects? In C++ gnu versions